# I just updated the flutter sdk and cant build application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, cross-platform

```
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'.
photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:89
  }) : super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind);
                                     ^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

Can anyone help with the solution for resolving this error?

Comment: As per error , it looks like you need to update library after flutter sdk update and manage your code with updated lib https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/changelog

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
photo_view: ^0.14.0
```

on my `pubspec.yaml`.
This fixed the issue for me-

Answer (score 0):

You must update your project after you have updated your Flutter SDK.

Execute the command below to identify the out-of-date packages:

```
flutter pub outdated
```

After, you may execute this command:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

or

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```